# how to do sftp python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sftp

I am using the code below to do sftp:
#!/opt/python3/bin/python3

```
import paramiko
import sys
host = '192.168.1.2'
port = 22622
transport = paramiko.Transport((host, port))
password = "p@ssw0rd"
username = "web"
transport.connect(username = username, password = password)
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
path = '/log/ERROR.LOG'
localpath = '/home/web/ERROR.LOG'
sftp.get(path, localpath)
sftp.close()
transport.close()
print ("Download done.")
```

But the output is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c.py", line 2, in <module>
import paramiko
ImportError: No module named paramiko
```

Is there no Paramiko module for Python3?

What do I have to use to do sftp?

Answer (score 1):

Paramiko does not yet officially support Python 3.  I found a bug discussing it, and SFTP is one of the problem spots:

https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/16

I recommend using `subprocess` to run the `sftp` command-line tool.